# Celery - Running subtasks inside group of chains

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

Hope all is well!

Issue: I am attempting to run a group of child tasks inside of a chain, then in the parent most level I have a group wrapped around the chains. The child tasks are being executed; however, the results from the parent-most group primitive finishes before the child tasks can spit back their results.

**Example**

--- I have 3 tasks below ---

```
@app.task
def task_one(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return [seconds + 0.1, seconds + 0.2]

@app.task
def task_two(seconds):
    return group(task_three.signature(args=(x,)) for x in seconds)()

@app.task
def task_three(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return  {
        'sleep': seconds
    }
```

---The tasks are called like so ---

```
g = group(
      chain(
         task_one.s(x),
         task_two.s()
      ) for x in range(1, 3)
)
promise = g.apply_async()
print(promise.get())
```

The function `task_two` will create a group of tasks (`task_three`) to execute. When ran, the outermost group will finish execution and return the results BEFORE the `task_three` tasks finish.

Any idea why this is happening?